# FireFox requires shortcut for link elment. Why?

Tags: html, firefox

Firefox will highlight my link element denoting an error if I use this form:

```
<link href = ""></link>
```

However, if I put it like this:

```
<link href = "" />
```

it is happy.  Why so?

Interestingly , if I peek in the DOM, I can see that is is represented as:

```
<link href = ""></link>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link elements do not use a closing tag. `<link href="" />` is OK because it's XHTML compliant, and HTML5 supports XHTML markup. `<link href=""></link>` is just the browsers internal representation and is only sort of related to source code. Browsers can do what they want internally.

EDIT. `<link href="stuff">` will also work.

Comment: `<link href="stuff">` is the preferred way to do it in HTML5. `<link href="stuff" />` is meaningless unless your doctype is XHTML.

Comment: Agreed. I think this was to smooth the transition for those who adopted XHTML.

Comment: @MattDiamant - "`<link href="stuff">` is the preferred way" - Citation needed.

Comment: From answer below ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Examples

Answer (score 1):

Here is the valid way of using it - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Examples

Answer (score 1):

Firefox flags the end tag `</link>`, because it is a syntax error in HTML 4.01 and earlier and not recommended (though valid) in XHTML 1.0, see item [C.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_2) in XHTML 1.0 spec. The notation `<link href = "" />` conforms to XHTML 1.0, and old browsers are known to deal with it, too (they simply ignore the `/`, because they use ad-hoc tag-soup parsing and not SGML parsers).

What DOM inspectors do is up to them. In the real DOM, a `link` element is an element node, and inspectors may linearize it in different notations.

What you should use depends on the HTML version you are using and how you are serving it. If you use real XHTML (i.e., XHTML served with an XML media type), then `<link href = "" />` and `<link href ="" ></link>` are equally good, whereas `<link href = "" >` without end tag (which is the correct notation by HTML 4.01) is a fatal error (well-formedness error, which means that no document is displayed).

If you are confused, stick to the classic `<link href = "" >` until you find some real reason to use XHTML.

Comment: I should have mentioned my Doctype is HTML 5.

Comment: @stack_temp, the doctype string is irrelevant to browsers except as regards to choosing Quirks/Standards/Almost Standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

From this page of the W3schools http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp:

> Note: The  element is an empty element, it contains attributes only.

So, it has to be used as a simple tag (`<link />`) only.